# how to create a ComboBox in website c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, combobox

I created a website in c# with visual studio 2015. I want that I have a DropDownList which offers me the possibility to write in the text zone,like writing in a TextBox..I have found that should be a ComboBox but I couldn't found thic component in my ToolBox in visual studio 2015..
This is the code of my DropDownList:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label4" text="Lastname :" runat="server"  ForeColor="#80FF00"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  Enabled="true"  Width="140px"  AutoPostBack="false"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: You will probably have to look for a third party control.

Comment: It's not possible with a standard <select> control (which is what your DropDownList becomes in the browser). You'll need some javascript for that.

Comment: how can that be? I have more searched but I couldn't find the solution..

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the below link,It works:
Download the project(link) and add the dll,css,Js,image to your project.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290218/Custom-ASP-NET-Editable-DropDownList

Below code i used and it works.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dtFields = new DataTable();
        dtFields.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        dtFields.Columns.Add("FName", typeof(string));

        dtFields.Rows.Add(1, "UserName");
        dtFields.Rows.Add(2, "Password");
        dtFields.Rows.Add(3, "Login");
        EditableDropDownList1.DataSource = dtFields;
        EditableDropDownList1.DataTextField = "FName";
        EditableDropDownList1.DataValueField = "Id";
        EditableDropDownList1.DataBind();

        EditableDropDownList1.Items.Insert(0,"--select--");
    }
}
```

---

```
     <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Index.aspx.cs"    Inherits="Index" %>
      <%@ Register Assembly="EditableDropDownList" 
      Namespace="EditableControls" TagPrefix="editable" %> 
      <!DOCTYPE html>

      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.position.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.ui.combobox.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
       </head>
       <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
       <asp:Label ID="Label4" text="Lastname :" runat="server"          ForeColor="#80FF00"></asp:Label><br />
       <editable:EditableDropDownList ID="EditableDropDownList1" runat="server"> 
       </editable:EditableDropDownList> 
           </div>
          </form>
          </body>
       </html>
```